# Detection accuracy of human vs bot. Which test to use and how to determine required sample size

Tags: hypothesis-testing, binary-data

I have a business use case around adverse news detection.

We have set-up an experiment where we compare the human vs a bot and we need to test it. The experiment results will come out something like this:
Case #, Human (0,1), Bot(0,1)

0 - No adverse news detected
1- Adverse news detected

Some quirks about our case:

- H0 is that the human is better at detection. So there has to sufficient evidence to disprove it
- We do not have ground truth label. In a way the human is the ground truth

What I need to know:

- How to test this hypothesis?
- What is the minimum sample size for this test?

Comment: to make sure I understood correctly your problem: (1) The trials are independent and Human and Bot also work independently (2) After, say, $n$ trials, you'll see Human guessed, say, $n_1\leq n$ and Bot guessed $n_2\leq n$. (3) you aim is to check if $p_1 = p_2$, where $p_i$ is the population success probability of each group.  Are (1), (2)  (3) correct?

Comment: 1) The bot works independently yes. 
2) The number of cases with adverse news will be always lesser than the toral number of cases (so yes n1 <=n, and n2<=n). 
3) Yes intention to test if the bot is as good as the human. Null hypothesis being that it is worse than the human at detection

Comment: Ok but in statistical terms _bot is worse than the human at detection_ is more suitably handled as an alternative hypothesis, since under the null you would have equality included.